# rfc 3339 timestamp decoding using r

Tags: r

I have  rfc 3339 timestamp

```
 example("2012-04-17T04:58:50.470Z")
```

is there any package which can help in decoding this value

how can it converted into hours and minutes using r language

Thank you

Comment: Yes. With `as.POSIXct`. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As Joshua said,  `as.POSIXct` and a couple related functions with "POSIX" in their names do a lot.  If you're going to be wrangling date/time strings a lot,  take a look at the `lubridate` package.